# Valid Data from forms

Tags: c#

No matter what I enter my data is always true. Im taking the data from a text box that the user can enter there data in. What am I doing wrong? Utility.ValidName and Utility.Email return true or false.

Check

```
string username = null;
string email = null;

username = textBox1.Text;
email = textBox2.Text;

bool vusernam = false;
bool vemail = false;

vusernam = Utility.ValidName ( username );
vemail = Utility.ValidEmail ( email );

if ( vusernam == true && vemail == true )
{
    Utility.WelcomeMessage ( string.Format ( "Hello {0}\nEMail: {1}\nWelcome!" , username , email ) );
    secondForm.Show ( );
    this.Hide ( );
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show ( "Please Enter a Username and Email Adress!" );
}
```

Valid Username and Email

```
 public static bool ValidEmail ( string email )
    {
        string strTest = email;
        Regex pattern = new Regex ( @"(?<name>\S+)@(?<domain>\S+)" );
        Match match = pattern.Match ( strTest );

        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( email ) || !match.Success )
        {
            Console.Write ( "\nInvalid Email!" );
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static bool ValidName ( string name )
    {
        string strTest = name;


        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( name ) )
        {


            Console.Write ( "\nInvalid Name!" );


        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for ValidName() and ValidEmail()?  It would seem your problem is probably there

Comment: what's going wrong? what do validname and email return when you give them bad data? have you stepped through it using a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always return true, no matter what.

Add a return false after your Console.Write. Simply outputting an error message doesn't cause your validation to fail.

```
public static bool ValidName ( string name )
{
    string strTest = name;

    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( name ) )
    {
        Console.Write ( "\nInvalid Name!" );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Side notes:

```
if ( vusernam == true && vemail == true )
```

can be reduced to simply

```
if(vusernam && vemail)
```

and `string strTest = name;` appears to serve no purpose at all.

Comment: lol thanks. I assumed if it got to the inside of the if statemen it would automatically return false.

Comment: 1+ for mentioning the code smell of comparing a boolean with another boolean. This often indicates bad namings and also bloats the code. This would increase the legibility: `if(isValidUserName && isValidEmail)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your methods always return true is because you are only returning true.

```
public static bool ValidEmail (string email)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex( @"(?<name>\S+)@(?<domain>\S+)" );
    Match match = pattern.Match(email);

    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && match.Success
}

public static bool ValidName (string name)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
}
```